# New Folder here shell extension that works for Vista?

Tags: windows

On Windows 7 Ctrl + Shift + N works but not on Vista. I found this
http://www.baxbex.com/products.html

but it doesn't install correctly on Vista.

So any alternative including tweaking the registry ?

Answer (score 1):

Barring a spot-on answer that involves a shell extension, what about an AutoHotkey script?  (I don't have Windows Vista, so I don't know if a script from Windows XP would match up.)  Although, my "shell extension" for Windows XP's Explorer has always just been Alt+F+W+F  (File|New|Folder).  Judging by your question though, I guess that a similar menu entry doesn't exist in Windows Vista's Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

CFI's **[ShellToys](http://www.cfishelltoys.com/default.asp)** will add the shell extension 'New Folder Here' to XP/Vista

```
All Shell Extensions
Add To Send To
Add To Templates
Archive Contents
Batch Rename
Browse Media
Cascade On Start Menu
Change Date & Time
Change Extension
Choose Program
Command Prompt  Convert Audio Files
Convert Images
Copy/Move To Folder
Copy Path
Create Virtual Drive
Delete On Reboot
Duplicate File
Encrypt/Decrypt File
Explore Rooted
Extended Delete
Extended Search & Replace   Find Folder
Folder Color
Folder Contents
Folder Size
Go To Folder
Image Size
Junction Point Target
Mask By Type
MD5/CRC32
Media Info
New File Here   New Folder Here
New From Template
Open In Notepad
Play Media Album
Portfolio
Preview
Print Folder Listing
Recent Files
Resize Images
Run With Parameters
Select By Type  Set Attributes
Shortcut Target
Shred File
Shut Down
Split File
Synchronize Folder
Up One Level
View Icons
Zip Files
Zip Folder
```

*Shell Toys is shareware, try before you buy.*

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for something free though